# Replace numerical values in a data.frame according to another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frames that look like this:

> ```
> DF1    
> Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4      
>  3       -2      -1       4     
>  55      45     -23      98     
>  12      43     123      23      
>
>
>
> DF2     
> Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4           
>   1      0       0       0     
>   1      1       1       0     
>   1      0       1       1
> ```

I need the following output:

> ```
> DF3   
> Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4      
>  3       0       0       0     
>  55      45     -23      0     
>  12      0      123      23
> ```

In other words I need to replace numerical values with 0 values in DF1 according to DF2.

PS: Each DF contains thousand of rows and columns.

Comment: What are the other assumptions about DF1 and DF2? Do they have the same number of rows and columns? Do the columns have the same names in both datasets? Are the columns in the same order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.matrix(DF1) * as.matrix(DF2)
```

But I don't even think the `as.matrix()` is necessary.  Just `DF1 * DF2` should do.  The reason why this works is because `*` is a multiplication on each corresponding component. This is different from the typical matrix multiplication `%*%`.